# Low voltage (self-oscillating) boost for solar powered pond pump

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, solar-cell, boost, joule-thief

Long story shortened:

> I am currently designing a small filter for my pond using a small pump
> (6V-12V, upto 540mA) with UV-C LEDs parallel to it. Currently, it is battery powered (9V, 6x1.5V AA cells) but I'd like for it to be solar-powered. These
> individual solar cells, however, operate around 0.65V(4W, 6A), which
> is why I would need a boost converter to step up the voltage. To
> ensure the operating voltage of the cells is more or less fixed, I
> would attach a battery to either the input or output voltage of the
> converter.

Summary of the system:

Input:

- Input voltage 0.6V/1.2V (two solar cells in series or parallel), I could cut them to obtain even higher voltages but I'd rather not as they are quite brittle. Sidenote: If I put 2 in series, I would get the 1.2V voltage needed for the YX8018 but the current would still be to high for that IC.
- Input current, up to 6A according to solar irradiance

Output:

- Voltage 9V (Led ([Datasheet](https://nl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/180/IN-C33DTDU1_v1.3-1484019.pdf)) forward voltage is ranging from 5-9V), so I took the maximum as batteries tend to drop below 1.5V as well

Here is a diagram of what I have in mind to clear things up. For now, I think that I should either put 1.2V batteries in parallel at the input or 6 1.5V batteries at the output but I am not sure what is best practice

[image: Filter system overview]

I want to design or use a self-oscillating circuit, like a joule thief. Something like the YX8018 ([link to datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/710956/Shiningic/YX8018/1)) joule thief would be amazing, as it protects the battery cells as well. However, I was unable to find a similar solution for higher powers/current that allows for day time use (YX8018 charges the batteries when solar input power is available and turns on the LEDs otherwise).

*Is there a market available solution for this that I don't know of or do I need to design a circuit myself?*

I have little experience building these kinds of circuits, so I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction on this. If there is an easier solution, feel free to add it!

Comment: You gotta show datasheets with what you have

Comment: How many solar cells do you have? Put them in series in order to get a higher voltage (at the same current).

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 unfortunately, I only have an additional datasheet for the LEDs, I only have specifications for the motor and solar cells that I measured myself

Comment: @DaveTweed I have 6 cells in total of 4W but I plan to use 2 for the project, I could cut the cells to obtain a higher voltage but in order to obtain the 9V I need I would need to make a lot of cuts I suppose.

Comment: UV-C LED's will be ~3V per  LED or 6V with 2 in series.. The trick is to match the voltages and supply adequate current with sun power. But the race is between IR heat grown algae & bacteria and UV-C kill so you need lots of UV-C power and solar panel. What system design specs are you following? or just wild guesses?

Comment: The UV-C LED I have ranges from 5-9V, it could be composed of multiple LEDs, I am not sure. I'd like to say that it is all exactly calculated but it is not, to be frank. Redenation: I know that the pump has a voltage range from 6-12V and max current of 540mA. Assuming a constant load gives a current of about 400mA, and power of 3.6W at 9V. The LED has a maximum power dissipation of 9Vx20mA = 0.18W. I assume an irradiance of 500 W/m^2 average, so I would get the about 4W from two cells combined (could add more if needed but it's okay for pauses in the system). Thank you for your time by the way

Comment: Redenation -> Reasoning*

Comment: Where did you get the cells from? Why don't you use a small solar panel? It will most likely give 21 V open circuit and will happily charge a 12 V battery.

Comment: @AbdullahBaig I got the cells as a gift, they are 15.5x15.5cm cells. Of course, I could buy a panel, but it would be relatively expensive compared to a boost converter (or so I think) and I think it would be nice to use these cells. Also, in the end, wouldn't stepping down the voltage be the same as boosting the voltage? (Or did I misunderstand?)